# PHP traits have me discombobulated

Tags: traits

I am trying to use a trait.

```
    <a href="{{ url('/users') }}"class="btn btn-info" >These are the users</a>
                                   
Route::resource('/users', UserController::class);

namespace App\Http\Traits;
use App\Models\User;
trait UserTrait 
{
  public function index() {
    $users = User::all();
    return view('users')->with(compact('users'));
}
}

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Http\Traits\UserTrait;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    use UserTrait;
}
```

So, clicking on the link calls the "/users", then calls the UsersController which then calls the trait UserTrait. UserTrait loads the data and returns it to users.blade.php.
But I get 404 instead.

OK, my 1st question: why the 404? The page exists in resources/Views.
2nd question: Am I doing the Trait thing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the second part.

It appears you may be trying to use traits in an unintended way.

The purpose of traits is to allow you to enhance a class without having multiple inheritance in PHP. If there is one or more methods that you might use in different classes, those would go into a trait.

If you might want to decorate the userController with a howdyhi method and the dogController with a howdydi method and a catController with a howdyhi method, but not the fishController and parrotController so you don't want to add it to the Controller class that you are inheriting from, you'd put it into a HowdyHi trait and then use it in all of those classes that need the method.  Think of traits as adding on methods or collections of methods. Similar to how composition works in JavaScript

I can't tell for sure why you are getting the 404. I DO know that the resource should work since it is looking for UserController.index and the trait index method should, probably, look like it is part of UserController but since the index is very specific to userController it should be part of the Controller and not off in a trait.
So...can't answer your first question, other than to say, I wouldn't do it that way